# How to extract a particular value from Json Node?

Tags: java, json

Hi I have Input of JsonNode type as follows:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "EventSource": "aws:sns",
            "EventVersion": "1.0",
            "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:270252992114:d1dd43d0-8bf1-496c-bc94-f4e70dec5032",
            "Sns": {
                "Type": "Notification",
                "MessageId": "923d528f-c844-5d49-95de-018f6d583bfd",
                "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:270252992114:",
                "Subject": null,
                "Message": "AAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAJGNvbS5hbWF6b24uY3VzdG9tZXJldmVudC5jZXMudGVzdC5OQQAAABDW7HxyIs4PvuXtarSxIxdeAAABALZT+4Yv09z9tK48/miZ6IhjvVCLixiH3GLltCxQzEkNgf9NTD57G744vdnw1D3LxLmxT4i0CCkVJJ5IPaH3Ud5Oy6MKa5wRrldtS6MTDMzKqoPwcdMiLm3AogonUAqyBYrxWt8fHrCYIlggX9EFW9Dk9ugDRrJuhCZqfVnt/wRUyP33DycwRKHBHSxn1XuDi9ZyEeCxrMLn9rGmpVvUQb3mdFReoVDmP4cEWcQEwYxG6/WvyimHGD5JtSxzlCR3rwddu8vXlp9Mq127+scPipAm83IJSw7CS5laZQZAD8qR4WwSfSZw8kq72y/LulhzWj3w7jbtOtmhbdnPyIN+L4I=",
                "Timestamp": "2018-02-16T09:22:36.149Z",
                "SignatureVersion": "1",
                "Signature": "f+23JQ6r9gZL6dRay4wqJHrX5CnB9cSVpPS/zgopPKHFOD5zvEpuTiGfuNf0e2L6/84pm6gK9xCEakzeaWtBAp7J/hFfbKQ2BSJ/GAKX1peG16Q8TS2k0NVxjzG4ImEHxf3i3ODOFJeA7WHxRZiMkNO+79lZDxkkOQdfWR3OEQ1yP8CjE4HLlLoSEUdk170AOw1nty9NZ6FOnsotLf5jce0GrXs1lkn7J/3nv/YlSqdMZEAR4SZDELCH3krQ4mUO7gwUfkDSFXsjWLarTayYl20eH3g/RZLQgPEQGTRBZW5wrknXg1vm4H4ICxxrGJBooAs7BCLkUVT1m4juRrlljA==",
                "SigningCertUrl": "https://sns.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-433026a4050d206028891664da859041.pem",
                "UnsubscribeUrl": "https://sns.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:270252992114:",
                "MessageAttributes": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I  want to extract value of TopicArn and Message, I tried following code but rawSns is coming as null:

```
JsonNode rawResource = input.get("Records");
logger.log("rawResource is: " + rawResource);
JsonNode rawSns = rawResource.get("Sns");
```

Does anyone can help me out in this?

Comment: What is `input`? Can you provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `rawResource` is a json array. Before getting `Sns`, you need to get the first item. Something like `rawResource[0].get("Sns")`

Comment: Input is JsonNode type object which is coming from some other part of code. I got above value by printing its value on console.

Comment: hector I am new to Json, can you provide the exact code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following:

```
JsonNode rawResource = input.get("Records");
logger.log("rawResource is: " + rawResource);
JsonNode rawSns = rawResource.get(0).get("Sns");
```

See [here for Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#get(int))

Comment: you haven't declare rawResource as an array so third line will give error.

Comment: @RishabhYadav Updated!!!. Changed line `JsonNode rawSns = rawResource[0].get("Sns");` to `JsonNode rawSns = rawResource.get(0).get("Sns");`

Comment: Thanks!! Saved my day

Comment: @RishabhYadav WC :). Also accept this answer if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely what you need.

```
var jsonObject = JSON.parse('{"Records":[{"EventSource":"aws:sns","EventVersion":"1.0","EventSubscriptionArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:270252992114:d1dd43d0-8bf1-496c-bc94-f4e70dec5032","Sns":{"Type":"Notification","MessageId":"923d528f-c844-5d49-95de-018f6d583bfd","TopicArn":"arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:270252992114:","Subject":null,"Message":"AAAAAQAAAAAAAAABAAAAJGNvbS5hbWF6b24uY3VzdG9tZXJldmVudC5jZXMudGVzdC5OQQAAABDW7HxyIs4PvuXtarSxIxdeAAABALZT+4Yv09z9tK48/miZ6IhjvVCLixiH3GLltCxQzEkNgf9NTD57G744vdnw1D3LxLmxT4i0CCkVJJ5IPaH3Ud5Oy6MKa5wRrldtS6MTDMzKqoPwcdMiLm3AogonUAqyBYrxWt8fHrCYIlggX9EFW9Dk9ugDRrJuhCZqfVnt/wRUyP33DycwRKHBHSxn1XuDi9ZyEeCxrMLn9rGmpVvUQb3mdFReoVDmP4cEWcQEwYxG6/WvyimHGD5JtSxzlCR3rwddu8vXlp9Mq127+scPipAm83IJSw7CS5laZQZAD8qR4WwSfSZw8kq72y/LulhzWj3w7jbtOtmhbdnPyIN+L4I=","Timestamp":"2018-02-16T09:22:36.149Z","SignatureVersion":"1","Signature":"f+23JQ6r9gZL6dRay4wqJHrX5CnB9cSVpPS/zgopPKHFOD5zvEpuTiGfuNf0e2L6/84pm6gK9xCEakzeaWtBAp7J/hFfbKQ2BSJ/GAKX1peG16Q8TS2k0NVxjzG4ImEHxf3i3ODOFJeA7WHxRZiMkNO+79lZDxkkOQdfWR3OEQ1yP8CjE4HLlLoSEUdk170AOw1nty9NZ6FOnsotLf5jce0GrXs1lkn7J/3nv/YlSqdMZEAR4SZDELCH3krQ4mUO7gwUfkDSFXsjWLarTayYl20eH3g/RZLQgPEQGTRBZW5wrknXg1vm4H4ICxxrGJBooAs7BCLkUVT1m4juRrlljA==","SigningCertUrl":"https://sns.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/SimpleNotificationService-433026a4050d206028891664da859041.pem","UnsubscribeUrl":"https://sns.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/?Action=Unsubscribe&SubscriptionArn=arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:270252992114:","MessageAttributes":{}}}]}');

console.log(((jsonObject["Records"][0])["Sns"])["TopicArn"]);
```

This online tool can help you understand the structure of your JSON : [JSON viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/).